# System of Equations $2x-y+3z+w=6$ and $4x-2y-z+2w=10$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Solve System of Equations $$2x-y+3z+w=6$$ and $$4x-2y-z+2w=10$$

By eliminating $x,y,w$ we get $z=\frac{2}{7}$

Also we get

$$x=\frac{y}{2}-\frac{w}{2}+\frac{18}{7}$$

$$y=1y+0w+0$$

$$z=0y+0w+\frac{2}{7}$$
$$w=0y+1w+0$$

So we the solution vector as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\ 
w
\end{pmatrix}=y\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+w\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-1}{2}\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{18}{7}\\ 
0\\ 
\frac{2}{7}\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now which one we should select as Basis vectors?

Comment: The set of solutions of a non-homogeneous linear system is not a vector space. What do you with  ‘ a basis’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of these equations don't form a vector space, but an affine space (a translated linear space).

A base for the linear space part is the two vectors that $y$ and $w$ are multiplied with. But is that what was asked? You gave a full parametrisation of all solutions (haven't checked the computations, but I'll assume it's OK) and that's enough.